# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Custom SSIS Components work in BIDS not in SQL Server Agent

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2, shopify, custom-component

We have developed Custom SSIS components that integrates with an online REST API (Shopify to be precise) and these components work fine in BIDS and every single time too.  However, when I create a SQL Server Agent job for the SSIS package that uses the components, some of the components don’t work, there is no error, just never hits the Pre Execute.  The components that don’t work call the REST API and set specific TAGS on some orders, they do so using a JSON.  The SQL Server agent is running on the same machine (my own) and it's executing the same SSIS package that works in BIDS.  There are no errors and the SQL Server JOB reports success.

My machine is a 64 bit setup, so obviously the Agent will be running in 64bit so there may be issues there.

This is what I have tried already

- Changed the SQL Server Agent user to eliminate the issue being a proxy/user issue.
- Changed the setting for the step to use 32bit runtime (Ticked “Use 32 bit runtime”)
- I have tried compiling my code using Any CPU x86 x64 .. with different results but none of them work etc
- The installation project (which is part of the solution) is a WIX Toolset project which can only compile using x86 which I don’t think I can change.
- Logged where it is getting to a log file.

I think it might be 32bit/64bit issue but maybe wrong.  The log file shows the following
When called from BIDS (works)
•   Validate (code running as 32bit)
•   Validate (code running as 32bit)
•   Hits Pre Execute and it all works thereafter

When called from SQL Server Agent (doesn’t work)

•   Validate (code running as 32bit)
•   Validate  (code running as 64bit)
•   Never hits the Pre Execute

Like I said, I suspect it being a 64bit issue but maybe wrong.

Comment: You missed two important bits of info: 1. Is the SQL Agent on your machine or a different machine? 2. What is the error message? (you said _dont work_ which is a very bad description)

Comment: Look at SSIS version on machine with SQL Agent and also at BIDS version.

Comment: Thanks.  The SQL Server agent is running on the same machine (my own) and it's executing the same SSIS package that works in BIDS.  There are no errors, the package succeeds but never hits the Pre Execute on the custom component.

Comment: Did you work out the pre-execute from the logs? Does it hit pre execute for other tasks? Does it hit pre-execute for tasks following it (with a success/failure constraint?) You might need to put some dummy ones to test. SSIS might not be the right tool for the job. Any tool can insert data into a database - it doesn't have to be SSIS.

Comment: yes, worked it out from the logs and there's a custom component above it that works fine i.e. hits pre execute.  It's the last task so it doesn't go any further but I will try putting dummy ones like you said (tomorrow morning now).  I think on this scenario SSIS is the only option for us because it talks to 2 different data sources and these custom components have been working with the API on downloading orders, setting them to shipped...etc.  I'm thinking I might have to resort to a Script task but that is the last option for me.

Comment: There's not much else I can think of. No conditional constraints? No expressions hiding out causing problems? variables with misleading scope? No dialog boxes? You've set up SQL Agent with your account (for now)? Anything in the SQL Server or windows application logs? No user specific paths (desktop/my documents)? Are there any logs on the component side? In times of extreme puzzlement I break out `procmon` and trace what the thing is doing inside the OS. It's very strange for it to not to run at all. What happens if you put it in a package on its own with no constraints?

Comment: Thanks for trying mate, I will try some of the things you mentioned.  I will take a further look at constraints but I doubt there will be anything use specific but still worth checking. SQL Server 
agent is running using my account.  I will look at the SQL Server Logs and windows logs on Monday.  The component logs never get passed the Validate stage.  Never used procmon but might be worth checking.
The idea that you've given me is that I will hard code the component to run on one specific order and put it into a SSIS package by itself to see if it works that way.  Thanks for all your help

Comment: From the command line, `dtexec.exe /file path\to\package.dtsx` This will help identify whether it's some magic with the VS invocation or just an issue with agent

Comment: I will give that a go tomorrow and get back to you all.  Thanks

Comment: Tried from the command line, dtexec.exe /file path\to\package.dtsx and the same results, Even tried calling the 32bit verion of dtexec in Program Files (x86). I think this eliminates expressions, conditional constraints, expressions hiding out causing problems, variables with misleading scope...etc Also eliminates the package running in 32bit version or 64bit version affecting the ssis custom components.

Comment: So when you run the standalone pacakge, it fires the package Pre Execute but not the custom tasks pre execute? What libraries does your custom task use? How does it POST (or receive) the JSON? I know it's laborious but...... trace the execution of a working run in BIDS in PROCMON then do the same in SQL Agent and see where it stops.

Answer (score 1):

Hi guys and sorry for not posting the answer.

First of all thank you for all your help, especially Nick McDermaid as you kept trying and trying.  I really appreciated your pointers and without them I wouldn't have solved it ( kind of solved it :o) ).

My SSIS Custom components only work when I have a "Success path" coming out of them.  This was only an issue on this particular occasion because it was the last component called in my Data Flow.

This could be down to a bug in my SSIS Custom Component but I am sure I have had this issue with other components in the past (I think it might have been the 'Send Mail Task').

If anyone comes across this issue again then I would love to hear from them.

I'm currently fire fighting at work so hadn't had a chance to look at the SSIS Custom Components again.

Once again, thanks for the help I received.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question is very old, but I thought I'd put in my answer.  I just ran into this very issue and the answer was that the SSIS engine didn't see the custom component doing anything so it removed the component at runtime.  I was able to get around this by changing the RunInOptimizedMode property of the Control Flow object to False.  After this I was able to run the SSIS package as a SQL Agent job.

If you run the package through dtexec.exe as bilinkc suggested in your comments, it should give you messages that make it obvious if this is occurring.

Comment: Thanks for your answer